# using 'is' where the type is defined at runtime

Tags: c#, casting

Can anyone help me? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong but it seems like there will be a simple solution:

Normally you can use `is` like this:

```
if (theObject is MyClass) ...
```

but if you want to specify the type it checks for at runtime this doesnt compile

```
Type theType = ...
if (theObject is theType) ...
```

I tried doing this:

```
if (theObject.GetType() == theType) ...
```

But that only works if `theType` is that exact type and doesnt take into account inheritance like the `is` statement does

I'm sure a solution exists (probably using generics) but I can't think of one right now (its the kind of thing you suddenly remember how to do the moment you click 'Post')

Comment: No, not this time. But you get answers so fast on Stack Overflow it doesn't matter!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you want [IsAssignableFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx), as in

```
if (theType.IsAssignableFrom(theObject.GetType())) ...
```

Comment: You got it backwards. The correct form is "theType.IsAssignableFrom(theObject.GetType())"

Comment: You're right, I neglected the OP's context.  I'll reverse it - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) or [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method, depending on the situation (usually the latter rather than the former). The latter is slightly more useful as it will return true if the type is the same as the one you want to check for whereas, clearly, a type is not a sub-class of itself. Also, `IsSubclassOf` doesn't take into account generics constraints whereas `IsAssignableFrom` will.

Answer (score 1):

The `Type.IsAssignableFrom` answers are correct.  The reason the way you tried doesn't work is because there are 2 kinds of "type".  The first one is the compile time type which is what `if (theObject is MyClass)` uses.  It is also the kind used in Generics.

The other kind is of type `System.Type` which is what your 2nd one is.  You can convert from a compile-time to a `System.Type` by using the `typeof` keyword.  The equivilent of your 2nd example would be `if (theObject is typeof(MyClass))` which won't compile.

There might be a more official or correct name for compile-time types, so if anyone knows it feel free to edit or comment it in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using IsAssignableFrom()?

```
if( typeof(MyBaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(theType.GetType()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) to do this, in addition to the equals comparison.

Comment: you are wrong, it is opposite method, from msdn: "If the IsSubclassOf is the converse of IsAssignableFrom. That is, if t1.IsSubclassOf(t2) is true, then t2.IsAssignableFrom(t1) is also true."